# Create graph (network analysis R)?

Tags: r, igraph, network-analysis, statnet

I'm quite new to R and having trouble with the following:

I'm researching politicians in Belgium on Twitter, and would like to see if any networks form within political parties on Twitter.

I have two data files

- The matrix file that contains whether or not politicians are linked
  (politicixpolitici.csv)
- The file that contains all the polticians with that respective
  fistname, name, political party, twitterhandle and parliament
  (data.csv)

I want to create a graph that shows the network, but with the nodes colored by their politicial party (this variable is called 'fractie' in the data.csv file).

I've tried doing this as follows:

First, I've tried to combine the files as follows:

```
rownames(politicicsv) <- politicicsv[,'TwitterHandle']
test <- cbind(politicixpolitici, 
              politicicsv[, "Fractie"][match(rownames(politicixpolitici), 
                                             rownames(politicicsv))])
```

=> I've plotted this network, but it comes out very sloppy and the names are on there which makes it very hard to see + the nodes are obviously not coloured according to the party.

Then, I've tried it using statnet, but when I wanted to create the the graph, I had trouble with the creation of the vertex attribute:

```
fractie <- get.vertex.attribute(politicicsv, "Fractie") 

Error in get.vertex.attribute(politicicsv, "Fractie") : 
  get.vertex.attribute requires an argument of class network.
```

Can someone help me in plotting this network, with the nodes colored according to the political party ("Fractie") they belong to?

Files can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7NBm46i0rRAcnowbUp5aUFDRHc)

Thank you, this would help me with my thesis.

Comment: "politicixpolitici.csv" is missing.

Comment: Just uploaded it again, must be there now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone help me in plotting this network, with the nodes colored
>   according to the political party ("Fractie") they belong to?

You could do it like this

```
df <- read.csv("data.csv") 
m <- as.matrix(read.csv2("politicixpolitici.csv", row.names = 1))
library(igraph)
g <- simplify(graph_from_adjacency_matrix(m))
# Color palette:
(pal <- setNames(
  colorRampPalette(categorical_pal(8))(nlevels(df$Fractie)), 
  levels(df$Fractie)) ) 
#         CD&V    Ecolo-Groen          Groen           N-VA Onafhankelijke 
#    "#E69F00"      "#81ADA3"      "#33ABB9"      "#18A56E"      "#C0D64B" 
#     Open vld       Open Vld           sp.a             VB  Vlaams Belang 
#    "#77AB7A"      "#2A6D8E"      "#BF5F11"      "#CF6E64"      "#BC82A2" 
# Vuye&Wouters 
#    "#999999" 
V(g)$color <- pal[df$Fractie[match(V(g)$name, df$TwitterHandle)]]
set.seed(1); coords <- layout_with_fr(g)
plot(g, 
  layout=coords, vertex.label.cex=.2, vertex.size=2, 
  edge.arrow.size=0, edge.lty="blank", asp = 0)
```

or try an interactive plot:

```
library(visNetwork)
visIgraph(g) %>% 
  visIgraphLayout(layout="layout.norm", layoutMatrix = coords, type = "full")
```

All in all I'd recommend exporting your graph to gephi and experiment with other layouts and visualizations there interactively.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is a great help! :)